# How to calculate the generating function of a Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics

> [image: 1]

Hi there, I'm trying to understand the solution to the question in the title. Can anyone please explain why the final summation is equal to $e^{λs}$?

Thank you!

Comment: That's simply the definition of the $\exp$-function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function

Comment: Ahhh, I see thank you! Will the process for other distributions like binomial/geometric involve a similar step where I need to just memorise the format of their power series?

Comment: Yes, you are right in some sense. Have a look at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Binomial_Distribution and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Probability_Generating_Function_of_Geometric_Distribution. I hope these proofs belong to your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be presumed to have learned in calculus before studying probability that
$$
e^a = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a^i}{i!}. \tag 1
$$
Without that, the function $i \mapsto \dfrac{\lambda^i}{i!} e^{-\lambda}$ for $i=0,1,2,3,\ldots$ would not be a probability mass function, since only line $(1)$ above tells you that the sum of that over all values of $i$ is $1.$

Kai-Lai Chung's undergraduate introduction to probability, in at least one of its editions, says:

> "Everybody knows" that $$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

complete with quotation marks around those two words.